# What does '(?=' and ')' do here?

Tags: python, regex

The code here is to find out the number of sub strings.
I tried other methods but using this line the code was shorter and worked just the same.

```
count=len(re.findall('(?='+sub_string+')', string))
```

This is might provide some context.

```
import re
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count=len(re.findall('(?='+sub_string+')', string))
    return count
```

Comment: This `(?=..)` will do a _bump-along_ overlap matches. Is that what you're asking ?

Comment: See this https://regex101.com/r/iHXnJC/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'?=' Is part of a positive look ahead assertion. You're capturing matches up to, but not including your sub_string.

For your purposes, this may be more succinct.

```
count = len(re.findall(sub_string, string))
```

A more thorough explanation of regex assertions can be found here.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

This code uses [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `?=` is literal of [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It tell regular expression process to search next match also in previous.

[Example 1](https://regex101.com/r/HLgJN8/1), [Example 2](https://regex101.com/r/HLgJN8/2) - you can see difference with positive lookahead(1) and without(2).